# API to add test users access to unverified app

Tags: google-api

I'm new to google cloud API. I need to know, does Google have any API to add test users who can access your app while its status is in testing? Attach is the image below to what I mean. I'm glad if anyone could help me out. Thanks!

[image: Here is the consent screen where the test users are manually added]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API that will allow you to access Google cloud console in this manner test users need to be added by the developer for security reasons

once you're application is in production you won't need to authorize users in this manner.

btw test users have nothing to do with wether or not the app is verified it's wether or not its in test or production.  These are separate concepts